# Stuck in a login loop after downloading NVIDIA drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics

Yo! I'm a newbie to Linux and need some easy to understand help on trying to fix my login loop after attempting to install NVIDIA drivers on my dual booted system. Most of my attempts at trying to solve this issue got me nowhere. Help?

My system dual boots to W10 (taking up 1.6 TB) and Ubuntu (400 GB), with both OS's being 64 bit.

IMPORTANT NOTE: 
I can only connect to the internet through my Android phone tethering as of right now, so I don't know whether that can cause issues or not in downloading stuff.